# Как скрыть .exe файл с панели задач после его запуска?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно я скомпилировал **.py** файл в **.exe** -  всё работает отлично!

Теперь я бы хотел, чтобы эта программа (.exe файл), исчезала с панели задач, но при этом работала (например: в диспетчере задач). Главное, чтобы она работала, но при этом не была видна (в панели задач)

---

> ВСЁ НЕ ОТВЕЧАЙТЕ Я САМ НАШЁЛ ОТВЕТ ! При компиляции с  .py на .exe нужно
>   было добавить -w  какое лёгкое дело ! и всё что мне было нужно ! А вы тут
>   всякую фигню говорили...

---

В скором времени напишу ответ
Ожидайте
но дело было лёгкое
А вам как-то странно показалось
или я плохо задал вопрос

Comment: если вам необходимо просто спрятать своё окно, то достаточно выполнить ShowWindow(<your_wnd_desciptor>, SW_HIDE), если вам необходимо спрятать свою программу из дистпетчера, то необходимо писать хук для системной библиотеки, которая отвечает за выдачу информации о процессах (емнип, kernel32.dll или ntdll.dll)

Comment: "программа" не может "работать" в панели задач или диспетчере задач. Просто не открывайте окно, @C_KaBiR и все будет ок - оно не будет отображаться.

Comment: Народ
Я хочу чтобы программа ПОСЛЕ ЗАПУСКА (после её открытия) работала, НО НЕ БЫЛА ВИДНА пользователю...
Понимаете ? По-этому я написал 
ЧТОБЫ ОНА НЕ БЫЛА ВИДНА В ПАНЕЛИ ЗАДАЧ
НО РАБОТАЛА В ДИСПЕТЧЕРЕ ЗАДАЧ

Comment: @C_KaBiR, чем собирали? pyinstaller? Если смогли сами разобраться, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ответ с решением. Писать решение в вопросе неправильно, лучше сделать как ответ. И не пишите капсом или с излишним добавлением смайлов, это не сделает ваши сообщения лучше. Кст, у вас консольное приложение или оконное?

Answer (score 1):

[Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://windowsnotes.ru/programs/kak-zapustit-prilozhenie-v-vide-sluzhby-windows/) Можно запускать как службу

создать:
`..\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe install vaduxa_http c:\Python37-64\python.exe e:\vaduxa\save\STAND\start_www.py`

удалить: `..\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe remove vaduxa_http`

Answer (score 0):

Написать как консольное, слинковать как оконное...

В Visual C++ - сделать консольное, и поменять тип:

```
editbin.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS prog.exe
```

Только не пытайтесь выводить в `cout` или читать `cin` :) - ну, в смысле, работать с экраном/клавиатурой.

Comment: ага, главное, что бы человек не использовал printf/puts:)

Comment: весьма опасный совет, кроме cin/cout там еще куча неявных подводных камней, к тому же это питон, бог знает, что там и как линкуется в конечный .ехе